# How to access the arrays in private class of C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11, private

```
class bus {

private:    
    string arr[10] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

public:     
    void reservation();

};
```

Here, I have a private array that I want to access and make changes through the reservation() in public class.

```
void bus::reservaton() {

cout << "What should I write in here to change the 3rd and 7th index of the 
above array to \"not empty\"" << endl;

}
```

Suppose, I want to make the 3rd and 7th index to "not empty", what should I write there?

Sample:-

```
string arr[10] = { "0", "1", "2", "not empty", "4", "5", "6", "not empty", "8", "9" };
```

And do I need to make any changes in the main function? If yes, then can you please help me by writing it down. 
Thank you.

Comment: `arr[3] = "not empty"`?

Comment: member functions have access to private members, otherwise both would be pretty useless

Comment: The best course of action at this point would be to read a book or at least a tutorial on C++. Seriously.

Comment: Where's your private class?

Answer (score 0):

[How to use arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_arrays.htm)

```
void bus::reservation() {
  arr[3] = "not empty";
  arr[7] = "not empty";
}
```

Comment: It s syntaxic sugar, the full syntax is " this.arr[3] = "not empty"; "

Comment: @RomanGrout replace "full" with "wrong" and your comment is correct :P `this` is a pointer and `this.arr` wont work. Anyhow wether to write `this->` in front of a member is purely a matter of taste

Comment: @tobi303 don't be so harsh... also one note there are circumstances where `this->` isn't just a matter of taste :)

Comment: @W.F. that comment wasnt meant to be harsh. Just wanted to make sure that misinformation gets corrected. And thanks for pointing out my piece of misinformation ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this, a simple [assignment operator (=)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) would work.

For example, in the following example, the value at index `1` is changed:

```
std::string slist[ 3 ] { "a", "b", "c" }; 
slist[ 1 ] = "Changed!";
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/rO9hwt

BTW, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `std::string` instead of an array. And, take a look at its member function [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) for accessing the value of an index with `out of bounds` checking.

Live example: http://ideone.com/bcHZpY